# iptables not opening 443

Tags: apache-2.2, iptables

Requests through `https` to my domain time out. Seems the firewall is still closed despite my tries.

Running Debian

```
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 7.11 (wheezy)
Release:        7.11
Codename:       wheezy



sudo netstat -ntlp

...
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      2224/apache2
...
```

My current iptables rules:

```
# Generated by iptables-save v1.4.14 on Sat Jan 13 23:32:19 2018
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [1718:285832]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1521:341387]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

Apache conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin contact@domain.com
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAlias www.domain.com

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile "/etc/apache2/cert/domain.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/etc/apache2/cert/domain.key"
    SSLCACertificateFile "/etc/apache2/cert/domain.ca-bundle"

    <Directory /var/www/domain>
                Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride None
                Order allow,deny
                allow from all
        </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
                AllowOverride None
                Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.err
    LogLevel warn

        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/domain.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Where did you host this service?

Answer (score 2):

First of all your "*-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 443 -j ACCEPT*" rule does nothing as your default policy is to ACCEPT everything.

In order to accept HTTPS **only** your rules should rather be as follows:

```
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED -m tcp --dport https -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

That said, the content of your saved rules with iptables-save does not really reflect active rules on your machine. Use the following commands to find out active rules:

```
iptables -t filter -nL # main command to exec
iptables -t mangle -nL
iptables -t nat -nL
```

In order to apply your saved rules (in /etc/iptables/rules.v4) use the following command (install the iptables-persistent package before if it's not yet installed).

```
service iptables-persistent restart
```